# Can I avoid HTML formatting being escaped during API import?

Tags: api, import, html

I need to import HTML formatted content to a custom event field for a larger number of events.

During import via the API, HTML tags are being escaped and rewritten: `<a href=“https://example.com“>Linktext</a>` becomes `&lt;a href=“https://example.com“&gt;Linktext&lt;/a&gt;`.

Is there a way to avoid this and preserve the tags as they are?

Answer (score 5):

You can edit /CRM/Utils/API/HTMLInputCoder.php:
CRM_Utils_API_HTMLInputCoder->getSkipFields returns a list of fields that will be skipped on encoding. Add an entry for your custom-field to this list prevents the html-input from being escaped. The entry must be "custom_" + custom-field-id.

Comment: Is there a clean way to do the same?